# Upgrading System.Collections.Immutable to 1.2 breaks application

Tags: vb.net, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a working Code Analysis VSIX that used version 1.1.37 and I upgrade the NuGet to the latest 1.2 because many other NuGet libraries I want to use require the latest version. When I run my application with no code changes I get an error that the older version can't be found. This is the only library I have ever had trouble upgrading. If I roll back to older version application works.

I am running VB under Visusl Studio 2015 Update 3 which came with the older 1.1.37 version. Unfortunately if I try to set a break in my code I never got to it the error happens somewhere in Roslyn or System code before my code gets called.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project to make sure that no old binaries are left? Have you searched for "1.1.37" or "1.1" in a project directory to make sure that old references to the old version have been updated (*.vbproj, *.sln, *.manifest, *.config files should be especially important)? Have you checked that no of the libraries that you're using depends specifically on version 1.1?

Comment: Many people are seeing this, I have tried clean, also consolidate and nothing works.